# String/dict manipulation ' to "

Tags: python, string, replace

```
{'coolstring': {'stepone': {'X': '44', 'Y': '66'}}}
```

this is a string/dictionary that I create with input(), however, I need to change all the ' or Apostrophes to " or Quotation marks. The reasoning for this is that I need to do so for it be properly passed as a Json string further down my pipeline.

My idea is using .replace() but I'm not quite sure how to format it so that it swaps ' with " any tips?

Comment: Is it a string or a dictionary? It's not *both*.

Comment: "this is a string/dictionary that I create with input()"... What? This sentence does not make sense. Either it is a string (an object of type `str`) or it is a dictionary. Also: since you mention that you want to obtain a valid json value I think you should look into [the `json` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input is a dictionary, there's a `json` module which does exactly what you need:

```
import json

dic = {'coolstring': {'stepone': {'X': '44', 'Y': '66'}}}

json_string = json.dumps(dic)
print(json_string)
```

The output will be:

> `{"coolstring": {"stepone": {"X": "44", "Y": "66"}}}`

However if your data is a string, you can use the proposed solution from the other comment by using `replace()`

Answer (score 0):

If the thing is a string, then `.replace("'", '"')` should work (note the symmetry in using both legal quotes :-)).

Answer (score 0):

```
{'coolstring': {'stepone': {'X': '44', 'Y': '66'}}}
```

> this is a string/dictionary

Is this a string or a dictionary ?

If it is a string (if you use `input()` from Python 3 or raw_input from Python 2):

You can replace the `'` by `"` using the following:

```
yournewstring = "{'coolstring': {'stepone': {'X': '44', 'Y': '66'}}}".replace("'", '"')
```

If it is a dictionary (if you use `input()` from Python 2):

Here the `'` are used as the string delimiters. Python can use both `"` and `'` for delimiting strings. You can convert this dictionary to a JSON string by using:

```
import json
yourjson = json.dumps({'coolstring': {'stepone': {'X': '44', 'Y': '66'}}})
```

Comment: The end result is a dictionary built up by a number of small strings which are created through the input() function.

Comment: Then you just have to convert this dictionary to a valid JSON string by using `json.dumps({'your': 'dictionary'})`